# How to deal with freezes caused by autofs after network disconnect

Tags: automounting, cifs, sshfs, kubuntu, autofs

I mount four servers (3 via `cifs`, 1 via `sshfs`) using `autofs`.

`auto.master`

```
/- /etc/auto.all --timeout=60 --ghost
```

`auto.all`

```
/mnt \
  /server1        -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/etc/.smbcredentials.txt,uid=1000,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,users ://server1/ \
  /server2/      -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/etc/.smbcredentials.txt,uid=1000,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,users ://server2/ \
  /server3   -fstype=cifs,rw,credentials=/etc/.smbcredentials.txt,uid=1000,file_mode=0775,dir_mode=0775,users ://server3/ \
  /server4        -fstype=fuse,rw,allow_other,uid=1000,users,reconnect,cache=yes,kernel_cache,compression=no,large_read,Ciphers=arcfour :sshfs\#user@server\:/home
```

```

Everything is fine when I make a clean boot.
I connect to my network (using a VPN) and `autofs` mounts everything.

## Problem

When there is a network disconnect, e.g. when I hibernate my laptop or connect to a different network, `autofs` causes my explorer (dolphin) to freeze because it tries to load the remote share infinitely.

It becomes unresponsive and does not even react to SIGTERM commands.
Sometimes I am lucky and calling `sudo service autofs stop` and `sudo automount` helps to resolve the issue.
However, often it still stays freezed. 
Sometimes even, my whole dock freezes due to this making all applications unselectable. Then I have to make a full reboot..

I've searched for weeks now for solution how to deal with `autofs` in such situations. Before using `autofs`, I had everything mounted via `/etc/fstab` but that also required a manual remount after every network interruption.

I thought `autofs` would help me here but it causes me even more trouble.

## Questions

1. Is there any point I overlooked that could solve the freezing problem?
2. Is there a completely different approach that may be better suited for my situation than `autofs`?

PS: I'm on Kubuntu 16.04

Comment: I wonder if your problems relate to the fact that you are using CIFS and SSHFS with autofs. I've never used it except with NFS...

Comment: The main problems definitely arise from the `sshfs` mount in this case. I'll try to replace it with `nfs` later and see if that helps.

Comment: One of the advantages that autofs provides is that it reduces the duration that network filesystems are mounted - they're mounted as needed and autofs will unmount them soon after they're no longer being used. If you suspend while a network filesystem is mounted (regardless of whether it was mounted manually or via fstab or by autofs) and resume when the remote system isn't reachable, things will likely hang. autofs wont change that. You can try `umount -f /mountpoint` to forcibly unmount it.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks for the wrap up, most of it was known to me. I just experience less issues when using a manual mount. When I use an alias to automatically umount and mount as desired, it causes less troubles then dealing with `autofs` where I also need to stop the `autofs` service. I would like to use `autofs` but together with `sshfs` and a lot of network and VPN disconnects its a nightmare currently.

Comment: Regarding my thinking to replace it with `nfs`: Since my IP address changes a lot due to different networks this is not an option.

Answer (score -1):

you can add "soft" option, so it generates an error when a timeout has been exceeded. By default, you are using a hard mount, meaning... it will hold on to the nfs mount and retry forever.

WARNING: soft mount will abort any i/o once the timeout has been exceeded due to errors (network timeout, etc), if there's something in the cache that's not written to the nfs mount, there's a chance you might loose it.

Comment: This is incorrect, the *autofs* service mounts shares as needed and unmount them after a period of inactivity, so it will _not_  hold on to the mount and retry forever.

Comment: The `soft` option you are talking about is only available for `nfs` mounts. I use `sshfs` and `cifs` here. So your answer does unfortunately not address the question.

Comment: have you tried? Isn't it that soft is a cifs mount option? 
https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs

Comment: also, he mentioned disconnect, i.e: connecting to a different network, the `autofs` might still be connected and the resource might still be needed.

Comment: @MontyMontemayor yes option `soft` is available for `cifs`. However, the `cifs` shares are not causing the problems for me, it seems that most of it relates to the `sshfs` share.